# Delete all nodes and relations of Neo4j by RestAPI

Tags: java, neo4j, jersey, graph-databases

I going through the Neo4j documentation and try to develop a project using Graph database. As we know theirs is two-way to address Neo4j DB by embedded way or RestAPI. Embedded way is working fine for everything but the problem in RestAPI.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-java-rest-client-example.html

I have created a java client that mention in as the documentation by using Jersey. Everything works except when i try to delete all the nodes and relations. It status code is 405. I could understand even if i give /transaction/commit URL it throw this error.

```
String SERVER_ROOT_URI = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/";
this.SERVER_ROOT_URI = SERVER_ROOT_URI + "transaction/commit";
this.resource = Client.create().resource(SERVER_ROOT_URI);

String cql = "MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]";
ClientResponse response = resource.accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ).type( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ).entity(this.getPayload(cql)).post(ClientResponse.class );


System.out.println("Response state:"+response.getStatus());
```

Output: 405(method not allowed)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, but `"MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]"` query is not a DELETE request to send the REST API. I think API recognises the query as a GET or POST request.

EDIT:
Just come up with this [issue](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-clean-remote-db-addon/issues/10) in Github. May it helps

Comment: Which mean that they're no way to delete those nodes and relations by using a post or a get?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the actual operation or a return value to your cypher query.

```
MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r
```

Otherwise on the http level your request looks good.

Just make sure to close the response when you're done.

```
String SERVER_ROOT_URI = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/";
this.SERVER_ROOT_URI = SERVER_ROOT_URI + "transaction/commit";
this.resource = Client.create().resource(SERVER_ROOT_URI);

String cql = "MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r";
ClientResponse response = resource.accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ).type( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ).entity(this.getPayload(cql)).post(ClientResponse.class );


System.out.println("Response state:"+response.getStatus());
```

Comment: Nope still not working and be the same error code 405 even if i use delete request.

Comment: If you profile the request that is executed, can you confirm the request is a POST request ?

Comment: It is not Post request it is Delete request. http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-nodes.html#rest-api-delete-node